# Disabling every GameObject except one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a book where if the user press the pages it `SetActive(false)` every `GameObject` except the selected `GameObject`.

```cs
public GameObject[] bookPages;
int currentPage;
    
public void whatPage ( )
{
    int pages = 0;
    while ( pages < bookPages.Length )
    {
        if ( pages == currentPage )
        {
            Debug.Log ( "CURRENT PAGE" + currentPage );
            bookPages [ currentPage ].SetActive ( true );
            pages++;
            continue;
        }
        bookPages [ pages ].SetActive ( false );
        Debug.Log ( pages );
        pages++;
    }
}

public void pageFlu ( )
{
    currentPage = 1;
    whatPage ( );
    bookPages [ currentPage ].SetActive ( true );
}
```

I have tried the `continue` method.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: all pages are set to inactive

Comment: Just make two int variables CurrentPage NextPage. And play with them because You have only one page that is active and wehn choosing a new page you disable it and enable the new one.

Comment: Thank you so much but I have 6 pages hehe

Comment: the code will work even with infinite pages, all you need is to control active page and next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach to this problem would be keeping track of the last active page and deactivating it when any other page is being selected. That would be a lot faster.

You could also write a function that takes the selected page as parameter, deactivates current page, assigns current page to the selected page parameter and activates the selected page. Something like this:

```cs
public GameObject[] bookPages;
int currentPage;

public void DeactivateAllPages()
{
    foreach (GameObject page in bookPages)
    {
        page.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void SelectPage(int pageIndex)
{
    bookPages[currangePage].SetActive(false);

    currangePage = pageIndex;

    bookPages[currangePage].SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: what if I have like 6 pages then I only want page 4 to be active then the rest are inactive?

Comment: You will have to deactivate them all in the initialization (Start function probably). Then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I see a spelling mistake in your original code. You had `currentPage`  instead of `currentPage`. That would certainly cause Unity to stop the execution of that method. You would see a red Exception message in your console log.

But to make the code simpler, you could approach it something like this:

```cs
public GameObject[] bookPages;
int currentPage;
    
public void whatPage ( )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < bookPages.Length; i++ )
        // also handles a bad 'currentPage' value by setting all to inactive.
        bookPages [ i ].SetActive ( i == currentPage ); 
}

public void pageFlu ( )
{
    currentPage = 1;
    whatPage ( );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I don't see where I deactivate them

Comment: @NicoleErasga at the end of `SetActive ( i == currentPage )`. That means that if `i` is equal to the current page, the item will be active. If `i` is not equal to the current page, that’s `false` and the item is set to inactive. It’s a “brute force” that will go through and check all item. So, if you set currentPage to -1 for example, NO items will be active; they’ll all be set to inactive.

Comment: I see I haven't thought that it can work like this wow